# GDAL SetGeoTransform does not work as expected

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff

No transformation is visible after using `SetGeoTransform` to the dataset opened from a *.tiff file:

```
ds = gdal.Open(filename, GA_ReadOnly) # open the raster data set

geo_transform = (0.3,10,30,-10,80,-1) # complete random/arbitrary numbers
ds.SetGeoTransform(geo_transform)

cols = ds.RasterXSize
rows = ds.RasterYSize
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
data = band.ReadAsArray(0,0,cols, rows)
```

With plotting, I get the same results as plotting without the transformation:

```
plt.imshow ( data, interpolation='nearest', vmin=0, cmap=plt.cm.gist_earth)
plt.savefig('question.png',dpi=75)
```

GDAL version 1.11.3

Comment: What do expect to happen? When you set geo_transform you are only attaching some metadata to the image. I do not believe that imshow cares about metadata.  I would guess that you must warp the image based on geo_transform first and show the warped result. Probably this is worth reading http://www.gdal.org/warptut.html.

Comment: I cannot find this option for GDAL in python

Comment: Think you are pointing me in the right direction! But have not found a solution yet.

Comment: @API I think that  you should read first the Python topics of this GDAL Tutorial: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html

Comment: My grid is a 1x1m raster. So I found out that I'm actually plotting my raster instead of the values at their coordinates. I understand the problem now but no solution yet

Comment: You are opening the dataset read only, and not checking the error returned by ds.SetGeotranform().  Either open in update mode or open it and create a copy.

Comment: SetGeoReference it's not working with this code. (I think that I should need some more explications on how it's work...) ---------- """ Retrieve Georef & Projection from a reference image """ `ReferenceTif = gdal.Open(img_path_tif)
GeoRef = ReferenceTif.GetGeoTransform() #I take the geo ref of the ref image
projRef = ReferenceTif.GetProjection() #I take the proj as of the ref image` `print(GeoRef)
(654000.0, 0.3, 0.0, 4203000.0, 0.0, -0.3)` ---------- """ Set the Georef & Projection of a image """ `test = gdal.Open('test.tif') #Open a new image
test.SetProjection(proj) #Set the projection like

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax of your **geo_transform** is wrong (for this reason "No transformation is visible") but, with these parameters ("complete random/arbitrary numbers") probably QGIS it'll be closed (if you use its Python Console). You should use **geo_transform** with these guidelines:

```
geotransform[0] = top left x
geotransform[1] = w-e pixel resolution
geotransform[2] = 0
geotransform[3] = top left y
geotransform[4] = 0
geotransform[5] = n-s pixel resolution (negative value)
```

The correct syntax, e.g. a 30 x 30 raster resolution (in meters), it would be:

```
geotransform = ([ your_top_left_x, 30, 0, your_top_left_y, 0, -30 ])
```

by using square brackets in the list notation for the six parameters.

Comment: I was aware of the parameter, but putting them into brackets has no effect

Comment: You need to close the datasets, `ds = None`, after setting **geotransform** to output raster.

Comment: Thanks but "Python.exe has stopped working" and windows can't find a solution

Comment: This works if your data has meters as a unit

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that the tiff file opened had no geo-information stored and so doing a transform on it would have no effect.

Comment: It had already geo-information. i.e. I get valid output with `ds.GetGeoTransform()` before the transformation attempt